# how to for_each through a map(string) in latest Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

how to for_each through a map(string) in latest Terraform?
below is what i'm trying to do-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDMZt.png)
Var.tf is below-

```
variable "resourcegrps" {
    type = map(object({
        name     = string
        location = string
        tags = map(string)
    }))
    default = {}
}
```

Below is Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
 for_each = var.resourcegrps
 name     = each.value["name"]
 location = each.value["location"]
 tags     = each.value["tags"]
}
```

Below is Tfvars -

```
resourcegrps = {
    rg1 = {
        name = "rg1"
        location = "eastus2"
        tags = { env = "test" }
    }
    rg2 = {
        name = "rg2"
        location = "eastus2"
        tags = { env = "test" }
    }
}
```

Terraform plan output -

### [terraform plan output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDMZt.png)

My problem is it doesn't add Tags. How can I achieve to deploy my resource group with tags?

Comment: I assume you want to add different tags per RG or do they all get the same tags?

Comment: Actually this was resolved. the tags can be different or same for both the RGs.
I was not passing the correct source module path in source ="...."

 
.Silly of me :)